# Entity Framework model update on a remote machine

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I'm building a web application that uses the Entity Framework. The files are located on a remote machine, the same is for the database and the web server.

In visual studio (2k8sp1), the path to the project is: \\Server\Web\XXXX

Now, I've generated the EF entities from the database, and later I've updated the database and added there a stored procedure.
When I wanted to update my model after that in visual studio, I was getting an error message that says:

> An exception of type Systen.ArgumentException occured while attepting to update from the database. The exception message is: 'A relative path is not possible for files on different devices'.

Any ideas on how to update my model?

ps. I also cannot change my connection string in the EF model designer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be using the Entity Framework incorrectly. The edmx files are source code, and should be treated as such. They should be added to your project, checked into source control, and edited locally on the development machine.

Try importing your model from your database into a local edmx and see if that works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [EDMTools2](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/06/20/edm-tools-options-part-1-of-4.aspx) tool for update your EDM Schema like that. Also you can use this tools routines in your code it's open source. Just copy inside of your project and call some functions like create model, create code from model..

I hope this will be help to you